# Clear all breakpoints in a Visual Studio solution

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a shortcut to clear all breakpoints within all projects within a solution in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

**Debug > Delete All Breakpoints**

or

**Shortcut** : <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>

This works in *Debug mode* as well.

Comment: FYI, this feature is not present in Express editions of Visual Studio (except for C++ Express, for some reason: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ft4yk3a3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 21):

I personally find it easier to hold ALT, and double-press D.
Which translates to **D**ebug menu, **D**elete All Breakpoints.

Comment: I don't have that option in the Debug menu, but CTRL-SHIFT-F9 works (VS Express 2013).

Comment: i wouldn´t recommend that, i just printed my code. Lukily only 280 lines and not a page with 1000+ lines.

VS 2017 - German

Comment: For me that would be Alt-D-A. It works but you have to check what the correct sequence is for your particular version of Visual Studio.

Comment: Oh the joys of localised softwares and shortcuts. Works for me as I have VS running in English, but beware of the possible "side effects" of your locale. As a colleague and @MaxW saw, in German this goes for Drucken (print).

Answer (score 1):

All of these did not work for me. Maybe because I was running it via WSL2.
What worked for me is <kbd>ctr</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>.

You will see the run popup, then search for "Remove All ..." and then select "Remove all Breakpoints" from the options.

Very easy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Vs Studio 2019

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (**D**ebug)+ <kbd>A</kbd> (**A**pply Code Changes) + <kbd>A</kbd> (Delete **A**ll Breakpoints)
- <kbd>Enter</kbd>