# Visual studio 2013 triggering break point

Tags: visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

I am using Visual studio 2013 always encountered a break point when compiling my code in debug mode.
Before this post I gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211234/clear-all-breakpoints-in-visual-studio-solution) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983918/visual-studio-refuses-to-forget-breakpoints).

I went through [DEBUG-> Windows-> Breakpoints] there is no break point available to delete any.

Below screenshot for how my exe triggering breakpoint at time of compilation. Yes, my project contains numerous libraries and this break point triggering only to library files. Could anyone help me to fix it, i googled a lot but can't?

[image]

Here is my Call stack copy:

```
    ntdll.dll!770cfe2c()    Unknown
        [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
        [External Code] 

DemoProj.exe!CryptoPP::MessageQueue::TransferTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation & target, unsigned __int64 & transferBytes, const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & channel, bool blocking) Line 27  C++
DemoProj.exe!CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::Get(unsigned char * outString, unsigned int getMax) Line 420 C++
```

When i debugging my code getting a error i.g "UMEngx86.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file."

```
'DemoProj.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'DemoProj.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sysfer.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DemoProj.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.1.4112.4156.105\Data\Definitions\BASHDefs\20160125.011\UMEngx86.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'DemoProj.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\~…\release\log4cplus.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
```

I also read [this document](http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/symantec-endpoint-protection-update-causing-0xc0000005-error) about this issue. Still need help from export.

Comment: At time of compilation? You mean your exe is triggering a breakpoint when executing, surely? Break when the exception is thrown and get a stack trace to see what's going on.

Comment: Yes, @Steve i simply click over local windows debugger and encountered this break point during compilation.

Comment: There can be hard coded breakpoints or the app could be calling the DebugBreak function. You can get breakpoints without setting one in a debugger.

Comment: @Kulamani: The locals window has nothing to do with compilation. I think you might be getting your terminology confused perhaps.

Comment: @Alex, yes as you commented i deleted .pdb from folder and compile again. Then again it created a new .pdb file and trigger the same breakpoints again.

Comment: @Kulamani: Post the stack trace! It's helpful to see the code path to the breakpoint, And I think you mean "debugging", not "compiling".

Comment: @Steve, yes right! i mean compile by clicking over " local windows debugger"

Comment: Could it be, that your code throws an exception? VisualStudio breaks when an uncatched exception is thrown...

Comment: @Kulamani: Seriously, post a stack trace.

Comment: @Steve: yes for the both case "debugging" and "compiling" it happening. i am little new to SO. How can i post stack track? Should i edit my post to send "call stack trace".

Comment: @Kulamani: When the dialog you posted appears click "Break". Then to get the call stack window: "To open the Call Stack window in Visual Studio, from the Debug menu, choose Windows>Call Stack". Copy the contents and post it here.

Comment: @Steve: Here copy of my call stack: "DemoProj.exe!CryptoPP::MessageQueue::TransferTo2(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation & target, unsigned __int64 & transferBytes, const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & channel, bool blocking) Line 27 C++
 DemoProj.exe!CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::Get(unsigned char * outString, unsigned int getMax) Line 420 C++
"

Comment: @Kulamani: I can't read that without formatting. Can you add it to your post?

Comment: @Kulamani: OK, getting closer. Set up the symbol server. Follow the instructions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b8ttk8zy(v=vs.100).aspx Once you've done that update the stack and post a comment so I'll get notified.

Comment: I'm guessing ntdll.dll!770cfe2c is the DebugBreak function.

Comment: Thanks @Steve your guidance resolve my issue on that call stack track. But again one more breakpoint appearing at another line. I am trying to follow same process but, not happening. Will notify soon after done.

Comment: @Kulamani: What I posted shouldn't have resolved any problems. Perhaps the error is happening non-deterministically (seemingly so). This suggests something like heap corruption. Perhaps it's not the DebugBreak function after all but a breakpoint triggered by the heap manager. Setup the symbol server so we know, ntdll.dll!770cfe2c tells us nothing, with the symbol server setup we'll get a function name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102604/discussion-between-kulamani-and-steve).

Comment: @Kulamani: It's not time for that yet. All I'd say is setup a symbol server.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Steve i have added some debugging ouput to my question explanation which is to complex me to understand. Could you have looks over it.

Comment: @Kulamani: There is nothing of consequence in there I'm afraid.

Comment: @Kulamani: It's a heap error as discussed earlier in the chat. Run some sort of heap debugging tool. I'd just use the page heap, again as discussed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i able to solve my won problem.

1. **What was the problem?**

A: It was a heap memory corruption, so Heap manager thrown a exception by triggering a automatic break point.

2. **Where you did mistake?**

Ans: I am explaining my mistake with simple example;

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char *buffer = "Simple Heap Error Demo"; 
    int len = strlen(buffer); 
    char *plaintext = new char[len];  //Here i mistaken

    /*It should be char *plaintext = new char[len + 1]; because i need one more memory cell for NULL character, that i forgotten and later i am trying to delete [] palintext. */

    memcpy(plaintext, buffer, len);

    plaintext[len] = '\0';

    cout << "\nplaintext: " << plaintext;

    if (plaintext != NULL);
    delete[] plaintext;     //Exception thrown here 

    system("pause");
    //cout << "\nplaintext: " << plaintext;
    return 0;
}
```

3. **How you solved your problem?**

Ans: First i neatly debug my project using WinDbg found where exactly heap corruption exception happening. Then i wrote a simple separate program related to same scenario and able to fix my problem.

A special thanks to [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366956/steve) who helped me to resolve my issue.